# AG Grid Stop Default Selection for Command + Arrow Key Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using AG Grid and trying to implement a custom keyboard shortcut that changes the grid's range selection.

See this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-mestorf-z7py5n?file=/src/App.js

My goal is for the keyboard shortcut CMD + SHIFT + any arrow key to add to the current range selection in the grid up to the grid's bound in the arrow's direction. For example, if a couple rows in the columns "Country" and "Year" are selected and CMD + SHIFT + LEFT is pressed, the original selection should stay selected, with the addition of the "Athlete" and "Age" columns.

This behavior works correctly for the right and down arrows in my sandbox, but removes a portion of the original selection when using the left and up arrows. So in that example with CMD + SHIFT + LEFT, the selection of the "Year" column is lost. Any ideas on how to fix this?

The issue that I've tracked this down to (so far) is that the selection is already changed before the `onKeyDown` listener is reached. Meaning the `cellRange` has columns Athlete, Age, and Country already selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was using `suppressKeyboardEvent` for the default column definition to stop the default behavior for this keyboard shortcut.